# Is there a way to change one field in all nested objects when this exact field in the main object is updated in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm making a school project - tree-like to-do list. To store the tasks, I have a sqlalchemy table "tasks" with that columns:

```
id | text | is_checked | is_nested_tasks_shown | parent_id
```

Also every task have nested_tasks property, which returns all tasks, where parent_id equals current task's id.

I need that behavior:
When I change the is_checked attribute of the task (`task.is_checked = True` or `task.is_checked = False`), all subtasks' need to be checked/unchecked too no matter how many subtasks there are and how deep they are in the tree. Can I do it in sqlalchemy?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a DB trigger. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm using sqlalchemy

Comment: I mean which database system are you using underneath. SQLAlchemy is the ORM / library you use to talk to the database.

Comment: @IljaEverilä oh, sorry , for some reason I thought about orm...
As a DBMS (and this time I should be correct) I use sqlite3

Comment: Very good, SQLite supports triggers and CTEs. If you do not insist on a Python side — i.e. application level — solution, then you could produce an AFTER INSERT or UPDATE trigger that sets the correct value on the child rows.